# Submitting a charge to square with a decimal amount

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to pass a POST request to charge a card to the `/locations/{location}/transactions` endpoint in Square. I have a nonce, a location ID and a Guid (.NET implementation). Everything works fine except I cannot pass a decimal value. I am using the Sandbox.

When I pass the following, the API returns 422, `Value was not expected to be a string`

```
{  
   "card_nonce":"VALID_CARD_NONCE",
   "amount_money":{  
      "amount":"225.00",
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "idempotency_key":"3f5f21a5-9d6b-4277-93b2-2b257a8e64df"
}
```

When I pass the following, the API returns 422, `Value was not expected to be a number 225.00`

```
{  
   "card_nonce":"VALID_CARD_NONCE",
   "amount_money":{  
      "amount": 225.00,
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "idempotency_key":"3f5f21a5-9d6b-4277-93b2-2b257a8e64df"
}
```

When I pass the following, the API returns 200

```
{  
   "card_nonce":"VALID_CARD_NONCE",
   "amount_money":{  
      "amount": 225,
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "idempotency_key":"3f5f21a5-9d6b-4277-93b2-2b257a8e64df"
}
```

It allows me to submit an integer amount but not a decimal. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use decimals if you are charging with cents in USD - the smallest denomination for the *amount* field is in cents for USD. You can set it to **22500** to charge US$225.00

Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#workingwithmonetaryamounts

*The amount of money, in the lowest in the smallest denomination of the currency indicated by currency. For example, when currency_code is USD, amount is in cents.*